# Dynamically resolve React components at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently investigating how to build an extendable application in React js. A key feature is the ability to add custom components to the application, both server side and in the client **after** the application has been built. Let's consider the server sends the following data to the React application:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "data": { ... },
      "component": "CarComponent"
    },
    {
      "data": { ... },
      "component": "BusComponent"
    },
    {
      "data": { ... },
      "component": "BoatComponent"
    }
  ]
}
```

The three components `CarComponent`, `BusComponent` and `BoatComponent` is not known at the time the application is built/bundled and can't be imported into the React application, instead they need to be plugged into the application. In the client I need to evaluate the `component` property to essentially produce the same result as if the components had been known at build time, i.e:

```
<ol>
  {model.items.map((item) => (
    <li>
      {item.component === "CarComponent" && <CarComponent />}
      {item.component === "BusComponent" && <BusComponent />}
      {item.component === "BoatComponent" && <BoatComponent />}
    </li>
  ))}
</ol>
```

In `Vue.js` this would have been simple because I can easily register components globally without importing them into any particular application **and** then resolve them dynamically at runtime like this:

```
<ol>
  <li v-for="(item) in model.items">
    <component v-bind:is="item.component" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

But no matter how I try I've been unsuccessful in finding an equivalent approach for React.

Comment: A hacky way would be to export all components from 1 module and then try `const component = module[item.component]; return (<component />)` but that is not the best approach as it reduces readability. I personally like to have a hard map as components can have different props

Comment: Look into Webpack Module Federation. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/